# Spark SQL passing variables - Synapse (Spark pool)

Tags: azure, apache-spark, parameters, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I have following SparkSQL (Spark pool - Spark 3.0) code and I want to pass a variable to it. How can I do that? I tried the following:

```
#cel 1 (Toggle parameter cell):
%%pyspark
stat = 'A'

#cel2:
select * from silver.employee_dim where Status= '$stat'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're running your cell as PySpark, you can pass a variable to your query like this:

```py
#cel 1 (Toggle parameter cell):
%%pyspark
stat = 'A' #define variable

#cel2:
%%pyspark
query = "select * from silver.employee_dim where Status='" + stat + "'"
spark.sql(query) #execute SQL
```

Since you're executing a SELECT statement, I assume you might want to load the result to a DataFrame:

```py
sqlDf = spark.sql(query)

sqlDf.head(5) #select first 5 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking another way, As mentioned in Microsoft answers from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/419296/spark-sql-passing-variables-synapse-(spark-pool)

**Cell 1**

```
%%pyspark
myVar = 'test'
spark.conf.set("myapp.myVar", myVar)
```

**Cell 2**

```
%%sql
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myVal = '${myapp.myVar}'
```